# How to retrieve data into textbox

Tags: c#, .net

MY VIEW::

```
 foreach (TSM.Models.Tasks itm in lstTasks.Where(x => x.Project.ID == item.ID).ToList())
            {

 foreach (TSM.Models.TimeSheetData itemm in ViewBag.HoursData)
 {
 foreach (TSM.Models.Tasks itm in lstTasks.Where(x => x.Project.ID == item.ID).ToList())
                {


     <td><input class="txtTaskHours date@(Date.AddDays(i).ToString("MMddyyy"))" 
                style="width:50px;" value="@itemm.Hours" type="number" 
                id="@(itm.ID.ToString() + ':' + Date.AddDays(i).ToString("MMddyyy"))" />
     </td>
 }
```

My Controller:

```
var query = (from ts in db.TimeSheets join tsd in db.TimesheetData on ts.ID  
             equals tsd.TimeSheet.ID where ts.StartDate == thisWeekStart 
             && ts.EndDate == thisWeekEnd select new{ tsd.Hours, tsd.Date, tsd.TaskID }).ToList();

ViewBag.HoursData = query;
return PartialView("~/Views/TimeSheet/_TimeSheet.cshtml", ViewBag);
```

I want to show data into the `Textbox`. To show data, I am using `ViewBag` by using foreach loop to show hours in the `Textbox`.

My `Textbox` data is saved in json.
This is my json value :

```
"TaskHours" : [{
                 "ID":"f2886ec7-47d3-e711-9666-000c297c9306:12042017",
                 "Value":"25"
               }]
```

I am getting this error:

```
   'Unable to cast object of type 
  '<>f__AnonymousType9`3[System.Double,System.DateTime,System.‌​Guid]' to type 
  'TSM.Models.TimeSheetData'.
```

Comment: It is pointless to pass `viewbag` along with `view` as `model` class. You need to remove `ViewBag` from `return PartialView("~/Views/TimeSheet/_TimeSheet.cshtml", ViewBag);`. It should be `return PartialView("~/Views/TimeSheet/_TimeSheet.cshtml");`

Comment: If i remove view bag then how i can take data in view from controller.just solve my error/@mmushtaq

Comment: What is `lstTasks` in your context?

Comment: @{
            List<TSM.Models.Tasks> lstTasks = ViewBag.Tasks;
        } This is my task list that why i am define this

Comment: But in your `controller`, you are not adding data in `ViewBag.Tasks`.

Comment: I am adding already that is my different action method..@mmushtaq. i think thats non valuable data..

Answer (score 0):

This is your code and pay attention to `select new`:

```
var query = (from ts in db.TimeSheets join tsd in db.TimesheetData on ts.ID  
    equals tsd.TimeSheet.ID where ts.StartDate == thisWeekStart 
    && ts.EndDate == thisWeekEnd 
    select new{ tsd.Hours, tsd.Date, tsd.TaskID }).ToList();
```

You are selecting a bunch of anonymous objects and then calling `ToList()` so you end up with a list of anonymous objects. Then you do this:

```
ViewBag.HoursData = query;
```

So now `ViewBag.HoursData` has a list of anonymous types. Then you do this in the view:

```
foreach (TSM.Models.TimeSheetData itemm in ViewBag.HoursData)
```

My question to you is this:

How do you expect the runtime to convert anonymous type to `TimeSheetData`? It cannot so it give you this clear error:

> Unable to cast object of type<>f__AnonymousType9`3[System.Double,System.DateTime,System.‌​Guid]' to type 
>   TSM.Models.TimeSheetData'.

Do yourself a big favor: I cannot see all your code but create a model specifically for your view and then put everything you need into it and pass it to your view. Some people call this [View Model](http://rachelappel.com/use-viewmodels-to-manage-data-amp-organize-code-in-asp-net-mvc-applications/). Your code will be cleaner, easier to read and less buggy. Stop hacking your way by sending anonymous types, custom types and ViewBag and this and that. Even if it was to work, it will still look ugly. So go and create a model as shown in the link.